# Forfiles Command Windows cmd - forfiles which contain 2 or more string snippets in filename do something

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, document, forfiles

I'm trying to echo a list of files which are named with multiple string snippets.  I have a folder with subfolders which contain PDFs named like:

> ```
> EDW_L1_C3.pdf
> EDW_L1_C4.pdf
> EDW_L2_C10.pdf
> EDW_L5_C2.pdf
> EDW_L5_C3.pdf
> etc.
> ```

A crucial point is that I can't be certain that the order of filename codes is always the same.  For instance, it could be that there are some files named:

> ```
> C2_EDW_L5.pdf
> ```

For context or if anyone cares the names contain a township (`EDW`), Lot (`L1_`) and concession (`C3_`) code and the files are land surveys.

I want to create a batch file to list the files recursively which have BOTH `L1_` AND `C3_` strings in filename.  For just `L1_` I have used the following successfully:

```
forfiles /S /M *L1_*.PDF /c "cmd /c echo @FILE"
```

However I am stuck at how to narrow that list to only include `L1_` files which also have `C3_` in filename.  ANYONE HAVE ANY IDEAS?
My end goal after I get this code to work is to copy those filtered files to a specified folder.  I'm just playing with code at this point to create a custom solution.

Comment: `Dir /B /S /A-D *L1*.pdf *C3*.pdf` or `Where /R . *L1*.pdf *C3*.pdf` should do it, _(although you may need to further filter those if they output files other than those you need, because you cannot always expect that either `L1` or `C3` is prefixed or suffixed with underscores)_. Granted these will also output the path, but for a recursive function, there's no point in outputting filenames only!

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.  I tried the first (dir) just to see what i got but it seems to give me a list of files that contained L1 followed by a list that contain C3...I need only files that contain BOTH L1 and C3.  I am pretty certain that L1 will always have an underscore after....sometimes though it will be L10_ though...which I don't want in search.  I would eventually like to be able to add a code to copy the found files to a folder located in the same directory as the batch file...is dir going to do that for me?

Comment: Phil, it's not as if you couldn't have modified what I gave you, like trying `*L1_*C3.pdf *C3_*L1.pdf` for instance!

Comment: That's a good idea...sorry i'm not a programmer....i just mess around with this stuff.  I was really hoping there was a simple AND operator i could add in between somehow...eventually I would like to have 3 search strings in prompt filled variables like EDW, L1_ and C3_

Comment: Another option is to grab all `.pdf` files matching a general pattern, then pipe the output through `findstr` with more specific  regex like pattern matching. There are many ways of doing it, including dropping batch files completely in favour of powershell, but you should have enough information on which to build a solution specific to your requirements now.

Comment: There is no reason to use the slow tool `forfiles`, so I'd rather use [`dir`](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) together with [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html), like this, for instance: `dir /B /S /A:-D "*_*_*.pdf" | findstr /I /R /C:"^L1_.*\.pdf$" /C:"_L1_.*\.pdf$" /C:"_L1\.pdf$" | findstr /I /R /C:"^C3_.*\.pdf$" /C:"_C3_.*\.pdf$" /C:"_C3\.pdf$"`

Comment: So I've finally been able to get the filter to work...I have been able to make a list of files that contain both L1_ and C3_ using the pipe into FINDSTR as @Compo suggested.  The code looks like this and sends the output to a text file:  WHERE /R . *L1_*.pdf | FINDSTR "C3_" > L1C3.TXT  .... Now what I can't figure out is how to take that list of files and copy them to a new folder located in same directory....i would eliminate the output to .txt file and simply create the folder and copy files